# highchart js half width line on zero (x axis)

Tags: highcharts

I want 15px line on zero. But only half on zero. What's problem?

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            lineWidth: 15
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 0, 0, 0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/9mzrey5n/

Comment: Can you provide more detail of what it is that you want?  I don't understand what "I want 15px line on zero. But only half on zero." actually means.

Comment: Just change your yAxis extremes, so full line will be visible: http://jsfiddle.net/9mzrey5n/1/

Comment: This is not that i want